# Most simple method or best practice to prevent default on anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html

Up to now (and if I can avoid the slander for not using unobtrusive JS !) I had generally been using anchors (for AJAX loading) in the following form with inline onclick attributes:

```
<a href="http://example.com/some/specific/link.php?hello=mum" 
   class="menu" id="menu_0" 
   onclick="loadPage(this.href, this.id); return false;"
   >Hello Mum</a>
```

I appreciate this overrides any other onclick event listenters but works fine for cancelling the standard anchor response of loading the href page in several older apps.

Recently I'd been looking through some (older) js manuals and online resources to develop some more involved event triggered code. I understand the ideas of Capturing and Bubbling, and the cross platform method of overriding default events with `preventDefault` and `window.event.returnValue = false` with an approptiate backwards compatibly `stopDefault()` function available as necessary.

So, I'm hoping that someone can advise on what is best practice here, or indeed what is really so wrong with this method of inline code that i'd previously used? Obviously I could change all the `return false;` statements to `stopDefault();` but is this worthwhile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1):

I always do this way :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.menu').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You can set your `event.preventDefault()` in a if statement or everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<span>` with a link class, and then dynamically re-add the link functionality.

```
<span class="link">Go here!</span>
<span class="link valid" href="https://www.google.com/">I'm a link!</span>
```

```
span.link {
    color: blue:
}
span.link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('span.link.valid')) {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        window.location.assign(this.getAttribute('href'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting, im curious where this sits with the graceful degredation side of things. I'm assuming that without JS you loose your links? but its one to add to the options, thanks